# How to invoke a REST service

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, rest, cxf

I have created a REST service which retrieves data from the database as per the request made and returns it JSON format.

Now, I need to create a HTML page with a button that, when clicked, should get the appropriate data from the service. I have learnt that this can be done through ajax. But am not aware how to do it.

The service uses Spring Framework and Apache CXF and retrieves data from a Mysql database, if that matters.

Code i have added to create my client:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#driver").click(function(event){
               $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/CxfRestService/rest/employeeservices/getList');
               });
            });
         });
      </script>

   </head>

   <body>

      <input type="button" id="driver" value="Get Employee Data" />

   </body>
```

Do i need to place my HTML page into my Java project and add the related configuration in my `web.xml`/`beans.xml` or something?

Comment: Googling for "REST HTML client tutorial" gives adequate results.

Comment: yeah i have googled and found how i can code using jquery.But i got the foolish doubt like how can run my client .I have my service written in spring and using cxf in an eclipse project.Now i have this client code written.How to run it? I feel this a stupid question but somehow i am more confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, all your service does is respond to HTTP requests. So, you need to send one - either

- direct the browser to move to a corresponding URL (`document.location.href = <url>`), or
- send an `XMLHTTPRequest` (aka AJAX) and parse the result, [for which JQuery has built-in functionality](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).

  - then edit the currently loaded page to include the results the way you like using DOM (see e.g. [Google on "jquery tutorial editing DOM"](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20tutorial%20editing%20DOM) for that)
  - See e.g. [AJAX Introduction - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp) for an AJAX overview. It describes how this happens in plain JS, `jquery.ajax` is a convenient wrapper over that.

You don't need to connect you client-side stuff with the Java project in any way - REST is specifically designed to allow them to be independent.